# How to calculate a scroll bar's thumb height with components that have different heights?

Tags: java

So, I am trying to find the calculations for a scroll bar. I have looked at other answers about creating scroll bars, however the most common one is similar to this:

```
float arrowHeight = 25;
float viewportHeight = 200;
float contentHeight = 600;
float viewableRatio = viewportHeight / contentHeight; // 1/3 or 0.333333333n
float scrollBarArea = viewportHeight - arrowHeight * 2; // 150px
float thumbHeight = scrollBarArea * viewableRatio; // 50px
```

However, I cannot use this, as arrowHeight changes depending on the component.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a Swing application? Or are you creating your own components with some kind of graphics framework? You should add more details and post a runnable example!

Comment: It's actually for a minecraft mod, using LWJGL (OpenGL library), so no it's not Swing. I've got an Array List of components that have their own height, and need a way to calculate the thumb height - I already have a way to get the Y position of the thumb, it's just the height.